# Make [standby] and [sleep] and [suspend] synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonyms, tag-synonym-request

I believe [standby](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/standby) and [sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sleep) and [suspend](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/suspend) are three names for the same thing. Currently questions are split between the tags.

Comment: Be careful though: `standby` is the general term for a standby mode that *not only* computers have (monitors, external hardware, etc.), but they don't have a "sleep" or "suspend" option.

Comment: @slhck: True, but all the questions under [tag:standby] are currently about computers.

Comment: Okay, perfect, then that's what I meant by being "careful" :) (and thanks for helping clean up the tags!)

Answer (score 2):

This is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).  As slhck pointed out, each one of these tags has a different meaning and connotation, and are used differently. Standby is different than sleep, for example.