# Merge [sleep] and [suspend] tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

The exact same same (as far as I can tell) operation is named `sleep` on Windows systems, and `suspend` in Ubuntu (those are the only two systems I can verify myself).

Would it be appropriate to merge those two tags?

*[There was a similar request for this already](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3040/make-standby-and-sleep-and-suspend-synonyms), however, it was declined with the reasoning that `standby` and `sleep` can be used differently; as far as I can tell, `suspend` and `sleep` do not share that problem.*

Comment: Personally, I think the distiction between `standby` and `sleep` was trivial too. As Mechanical Snail on the other question pointed out, the different tags are all used to mean the same thing, even if there is a technical difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure these should be blatantly merged, as "suspend" by itself has two meanings.

- **sleep** (Windows / common name) / **suspend-to-ram** (technical name) is where almost all the hardware is turned off, but the RAM modules are still continuously refreshed so that they do not lose their contents
- **hibernate** (Windows / common name) / **suspend-to-disk** (technical name) is where the contents of the RAM modules are written out to a file on the harddrive, and then the system is turned completely off.

I would instead suggest creating the above synonyms, and retagging the [suspend](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/suspend) questions to one or the other, as appropriate.